# runstats on a table without specifying schema

Tags: database, db2

*I am writing all this in a unix shell script*

I am setting current schema in db2 and then running a runstats like below

```
db2 "runstats on table <table_name> and indexes all"
```

but it's asking to specify schema again in the query and throwing below error.

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "<table_name>" was found following "TABLE".
Expected tokens may include:  "<schema-name.table-name>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Is there anyway I tell it to take current schema that I set in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to DB2 10.1, you *had* to provide a fully-qualified table name for the `RUNSTATS` utility.  If you are using DB2 10.1 or newer, then the `RUNSTATS` utility will use the default schema.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the command

```
set current schema xxx
```

For more information, please visit: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001016.html

You can also specify a set of schema via the PATH variable:

```
SET PATH = "SYSIBM","SYSFUN","SYSPROC","SYSIBMADM", MYSCHEMA
```

For more information about PATH http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001014.html

Comment: you don't understand my question

Comment: Ok, I got your problem

Comment: It seems it is a known restriction: http://www.idug.org/p/fo/et/thread=14073, http://datawarehouse.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/informatica-l/runstats-in-postsql-1310777

Comment: Why don't you use a Unix variable when creating the string for the runstats: db2 "runstats on table ${schema}.<table_name> and indexes all"